# Can I legally trap someone on my property that has committed a crime?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law

Let's say that someone comes onto your property with the intent to commit a crime. Not only that; let's say that you suspected this person would come to commit a crime, and you created a one-way door that traps them in a room when entered. You essentially set up a non lethal "booby trap".

Is this legal? Perhaps you didn't force them into the trap, but they wondered into it by themselves.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch, almost certainly not.  This is about non-lethal traps, eg. a closet with a door that is only openable from the outside.

Comment: I believe the jargon for this is a "mantrap"  (the neutral word "persontrap" doesn't work here, even google redirects it.)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is legal, but the specific details depend on where you live.  In general, it would be a form of Citizen's arrest.  Georgia law previously defined it as:

> A private person may arrest an offender if the offense is committed in his presence or within his immediate knowledge. If the offense is a felony and the offender is escaping or attempting to escape, a private person may arrest him upon reasonable and probable grounds of suspicion.

In other words, if either he has already commited a crime before trying to leave, or if you are have reasonable suspicion that the person came to commit a felony, then you were allowed to trap him as he is attempting to escape.

The requirements for performing this citizen's arrest vary much from state to state.  Just recently Georgia [changed their law](https://web.archive.org/web/20211019150229/https://www.legis.ga.gov/api/legislation/document/20212022/202470) to apply  to business owners suspecting theft, and a couple other cases.  Other states allow the use of non-lethal force in order to effect such a citizen's arrest.  Texas even allows the use of lethal force, if necessary, to keep the person from leaving your property until law enforcement comes.

More jurisdiction-specific details on citizen's arrest can be found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citizen%27s_arrest).

Comment: from your link: [Georgia repealed its citizen's arrest law.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citizen%27s_arrest#United_States_of_America) Note that citizens arrest laws vary WILDLY from state to state in the USA. If I recall, some states allows you to "arrest" someone, but not detain them :/

Comment: Good to know -- apparently now it has been replaced with a similar law that only allows you to make the arrest if you are a business owner, a weight inspector, or licensed to do certain businesses.  https://web.archive.org/web/20211019150229/https://www.legis.ga.gov/api/legislation/document/20212022/202470

Comment: Some additional issues: (1) usually a citizen's arrest is only allowed when you have personally witnessed a crime being committed (not the case for some automatic trap) or have been deputized in a particular instance after a crime is committed to aid a law enforcement officer, (2) someone detained in a citizen's arrest must be promptly turned over to law enforcement (basically, it would have to call 9-1-1 immediately upon being triggered); and (3) such traps would often violate fire codes and building codes. Bottom line: only very rarely a good idea.